# Laravel exception from 3rd party library not showing stack trace

Tags: php, laravel, bigcommerce

I am using the [Bigcommerce PHP SDK](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php) within my Laravel 4 application. The Bigcommerce SDK is configured to throw exceptions when errors occur. These exceptions are usually of the class `Bigcommerce\Api\ClientError`. When these exceptions are thrown, instead of seeing a detailed output in my error logs like I normally do for Laravel exceptions (with stack traces, line numbers, file locations, etc), I only see a single line in the error log, something like this:

```
[2015-05-05 21:19:00] production.ERROR: Client Error (404): The requested resource was not found. [] []
```

Is there something I need to do within my app to ensure that these Bigcommerce exceptions are logged using the same detail as other Laravel exceptions?

Here's an example of the error output I'm used to seeing from Laravel. This output was the result of a `Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError`. I do not understand why the output for this type of exception is what I'm looking for, but a `Bigcommerce\Api\ClientError` is not:

```
[2015-05-05 13:22:22] production.ERROR: exception 'Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError' with message 'Empty reply from server' in /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/bigcommerce/api/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Connection.php:213
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/bigcommerce/api/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Connection.php(326): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->handleResponse()
#1 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/bigcommerce/api/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php(225): Bigcommerce\Api\Connection->post('https://api.big...', Object(stdClass))
#2 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/bigcommerce/api/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php(436): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::createResource('/products', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/dev.example/app/spire_models/Product.php(873): Bigcommerce\Api\Client::createProduct(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/dev.example/app/spire_models/Product.php(35): Spire_models\Product->pushToExternal()
#5 /var/www/html/dev.example/app/extensions/SlaveTrait.php(26): Spire_models\Product->additionalSyncWithMaster()
#6 /var/www/html/dev.example/app/controllers/ProductInfoController.php(225): Spire_models\Product->syncWithMaster()
#7 [internal function]: ProductInfoController->saveProductDetails()
#8 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('saveProductDeta...', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(ProductInfoController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'saveProductDeta...')
#11 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(967): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'ProductInfoCont...', 'saveProductDeta...')
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#14 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1033): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#19 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#20 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#21 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#22 /var/www/html/dev.example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/dev.example/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#24 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Can you post a code of a typical error for comparison, or something you would expect?

Comment: @PawelBieszczad I've added some more example output to the question. Does that help?

Comment: In the `Bigcommerce/Api/ClientError.php` theres one method `__toString()` try commenting it and see if that does anything.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Bigcommerce/Api/ClientError.php theres one method __toString(). Comment it out.